# Creating amazon distribution group using HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-cloudfront

I went through numerous articles and forums online on how to create a distribution group but all of them are using S3 as origin domain name. 
I created a distribution group using origin domain name as rails server e.g `assets.abcd.efgh.com` I can access the asset if i do `assets.abcd.efgh.com/assets/abcdefghti-ieajife.css` but i can not access the asset using distribution domain name as `1234test.cloudfront.net/assets/abcdefghti-ieajife.css`. i am getting error:

```
Failed to contact the origin
```

The result i get using curl is

```
curl -I -s -X GET -H "Origin: https://assets.abcd.efgh.com" 1234test.cloudfront.net/assets/abcdefghti-ieajife.css

HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 507
Connection: keep-alive
Server: CloudFront
Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2016 16:48:17 GMT
Expires: Tue, 25 Oct 2016 16:48:17 GMT
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 8f18deab0e501ffbd2fa94cfd46e4785.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: PLAjGN5UuFEEFZSRYu_fGfsMDBcjH1w7Ruy1x1fv9bWiftWak3k1QA==
```

can someone guide me what other settings i need to do while creating distribution group or what i am missing?

Comment: *"i can not access the asset"*  It's very important, when posting a question, to remember that we already know it's not working... that's why you're posting a question. What we need to know is **in what sense/way/fashion/manner does it fail?** What error do you see? Use a tool like `curl` so you can easily capture the response headers.  What do you see in your server log?  What do you see in the CloudFront logs?

Comment: I get error failed to contact the origin and using curl  curl -v https://assets.abcd.efgh.com/assets/abcdefghti-ieajife.css -o /dev/null --silent -H "User-Agent: Amazon CloudFront" 2>&1 | grep HTTP
> GET /assets/abcdefghti-ieajife.css  HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: The point of using curl is not to suppress the errors, but to capture them.  Please send the request to the CloudFront endpoint, capture the whole thing, and edit it into the question as a code block, please.  You can remove your hostname if you wish, but the rest of the information, such as `Amz-Cf-Id` and `Via` are not considered sensitive and do not need to be removed, but you can suppress those also if you wish.

Comment: I updated the question but please let me know if i am missing something. I am new to cloudfront

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the origin needed to be updated to receive public requests. It was receiving private requests only